# Execution failed for task ':app:buildNative'

Tags: android, gradle, android-ndk

The same error question has been asked on SO, but their solutions didn't work for me. I couldn't figure it out myself, therefore I need help. Here's my `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

def VUFORIA_SDK_DIR = '../../..'
def JAR_DIR = 'build/java/vuforia'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    sourceSets.main {
        jni.srcDirs = []
        jniLibs.srcDir "src/main/libs"
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.qualcomm.QCARSamples.ImageTargets"
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 200
        versionName "5.0"
    }

    archivesBaseName = rootProject.projectDir.getName()

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            ndk {
                abiFilters "armeabi-v7a"
            }
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            debuggable true
            ndk {
                abiFilters "armeabi-v7a"
            }
        }
    }

    task buildNative(type: Exec, description: 'Compile JNI source via NDK') {
        println('compiling jni code with ndk-build...')
        def ndkDir = android.ndkDirectory
        if (System.properties['os.name'].toLowerCase().contains('windows')) {
            commandLine "$ndkDir/ndk-build.cmd",
                '-C', file('src/main/jni').absolutePath
                // Additional ndk-build arguments, such as NDK_DEBUG, can be provided here
        } else {
            commandLine "$ndkDir/ndk-build",
                '-C', file('src/main/jni').absolutePath
                // Additional ndk-build arguments, such as NDK_DEBUG, can be provided here
        }
    }

    task cleanNative(type: Exec, description: 'Clean JNI object files') {
        def ndkDir = android.ndkDirectory
        if (System.properties['os.name'].toLowerCase().contains('windows')) {
            commandLine "$ndkDir/ndk-build.cmd",
                '-C', file('src/main/jni').absolutePath,
                'clean'
        } else {
            commandLine "$ndkDir/ndk-build",
                '-C', file('src/main/jni').absolutePath,
                'clean'
        }
    }

    clean.dependsOn 'cleanNative'

    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn buildNative
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile files("$VUFORIA_SDK_DIR/$JAR_DIR/Vuforia.jar")
}
```

Gradle build always fails with this error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:buildNative'.
>   A problem occurred starting process 'command 'null/ndk-build''

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My reading of what you have here is as follows:

```
def ndkDir = android.ndkDirectory
```

May be returning a null value.  The other option i see is that

```
commandLine "$ndkDir/ndk-build",
```

Doesn't properly reference your ndkDir variable, and your commandLine execution fails on that.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:buildNative'. A problem occurred starting process 'command 'null/ndk-build''
```

aligns well with those two theories.

Try ensuring you don't get a null back when trying to asign to ndkDir, and/or converting the variable to a string prior to the commandLine command.